# How to prevent Cross Site Scripting attack in sharepoint search

Tags: 2013, search, security

In SharePoint 2013 how to prevent cross-site scripting attack, I deployed a publishing portal to the internet users and its enabled Anonymous access and web application enabled claims mode authentication.

I want to prevent no one can submit the scripts using the SharePoint search

For example:

```
http://site/pages/result.aspx?k={{%27a%27.constructor.prototype.etc
```